# RDLC Expressions

Tags: asp.net-core, report, rdlc

I am migrating from crystal reports to RDLC reports for my project i.e. in .NET Core. I developed my reports in RDLC and have used expressions in it. All of it works great locally. Now the issue is; on deploying I am getting the error shown below

An error occurred during local report processing.;The definition of the report 'D:/WebAPI/Reports/rpt_MyReport.rdlc' is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘[BC30560] 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler'.’.

Clearly there's some issue with expressions because on deploying a report with simple fields coming from database, the report works well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you publish parameters as below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. After R&D I found that if we used concatenation within expression in RDLC. It generates this error. Try to remove all the fields (expression) from the RDLC and put just static label text and generate the report.

Hope this should work for you as well.